# It is possible to automatically Create Chatter Polls

Tags: visual-workflow, chatter, automation

I am trying to figure out how I can automate the creation of a Chatter Poll on a Group Feed.

We would like the Poll to post when a custom Request  Record is in a certain stage. I managed to use Flow to create the Poll itself but I cannot seem to add the Poll Choices and so the Poll posts without any options.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to properly automate this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an outbound message to zapier when the request record hits that stage and then use salesforce api to post poll to chatter.

I currently use zapier
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_poll_capability.htm